# Best way to add users to a table that keeps track of chat conversations

Tags: mysql

I am building a chat, where users can start conversations with other users.

I am storing each conversation in a table that have these columns:

- conversations_id
- conversation_starter (this is the user that starts the conversation)
- conversation_receiver (this is the user that receives the conversation)

As you can see the table is limited to 2 users only. So what would be the best way to enable more users to enter? E.g. A second table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a table for conversations and a table for conversation participants?

**conversations**

- conversation_id
- conversation_name

**participants**

- participant_id
- participant_name

**participations**

- participation_id
- participant_id
- conversation_id

---

```
SELECT A.participant_name AS name, C.conversation_name AS conv_name
FROM conversations C, participations P, participants A 
WHERE P.conversation_id = C.conversation_id AND P.participant_id = A.participant_id AND C.Conversation_id = ?
```

The above should display a list of participants in your conversation.

Could then have a table for your actual messages within the conversation?

**messages**

- message_id
- message_participant_id_sender
- message_participant_id_receiver
- message_conversation_id

Plenty ways it could be expanded.

Comment: What if a participant is part of more than just one conversation?

Comment: You could have multiple rows in the 'participations' table. i.e. participant_id 13 could be in conversation_id 24, but also in conversation_id 25?

i.e. as two different rows: 13, 24 and 13, 25

Comment: Thanks! Works exactly the way it should

Answer (score 1):

You can create one Table with **Conversations** with  **conversation_id** and other data and a second Table with **Users** that are talking with each other with columns **conversation_id**, **user_id**.

In the Table with Conversations could be also a Columns with user that has startes a Cinversation ( owner ).